# How can I geolocate a bunch of IP addresses with Python?

Tags: python, geolocation, visualization, data-visualization

I have a list of ~300 IP addresses that I would like to plot on a map of the world. Can you explain roughly how I could do that with Python?

EDIT: I'm also interested in the visualization part of the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [hostip.info API](http://www.hostip.info/use.html). For example:

```
http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=64.233.160.0
```

So your Python code using `urllib2` would be:

```
import urllib2
f = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=64.233.160.0")
data = f.read()
f.close()
```

Then retrieve the data from that returned result.

If you require longitude and latitude, use the `position=true` flag:

```
http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=64.233.160.0&position=true
```

Comment: Pymaps (A wrapper for Google Maps API) looks to be your solution for creating the actual maps.
http://code.google.com/p/pymaps/wiki/PymapsHowto

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution in Python 3.x to return **geo-location** info given a dataframe containing **IP Address(s)**; efficient parallelized application of function on vectorized pd.series/dataframe is the way to go.

For plotting of records on the map, subsetting latitude and longitude information followed by using suitable Mapping API's like the Google Maps Api or tableau helps towards Data Visualization.

Will contrast performance of two popular libraries to return **location**.

TLDR: use **geolite2** method.

**1.** `geolite2` package from `geolite2` library

**Input**

```
# !pip install maxminddb-geolite2
import time
from geolite2 import geolite2
geo = geolite2.reader()
df_1 = train_data.loc[:50,['IP_Address']]

def IP_info_1(ip):
    try:
        try:
        x = geo.get(ip)
    except ValueError:   #Faulty IP value
        return np.nan
    try:
        return x['country']['names']['en'] if x is not None else np.nan
    except KeyError:   #Faulty Key value
        return np.nan

s_time = time.time()
# map IP --> country
#apply(fn) applies fn. on all pd.series elements
df_1['country'] = df_1.loc[:,'IP_Address'].apply(IP_info_1)
print(df_1.head(), '\n')
print('Time:',str(time.time()-s_time)+'s \n')

print(type(geo.get('48.151.136.76')))
```

**Output**

```
       IP_Address         country
0   48.151.136.76   United States
1    94.9.145.169  United Kingdom
2   58.94.157.121           Japan
3  193.187.41.186         Austria
4   125.96.20.172           China 

Time: 0.09906983375549316s 

<class 'dict'>
```

**2.** `DbIpCity` package from `ip2geotools` library

**Input**

```
# !pip install ip2geotools
import time
s_time = time.time()
from ip2geotools.databases.noncommercial import DbIpCity
df_2 = train_data.loc[:50,['IP_Address']]
def IP_info_2(ip):
    try:
        return DbIpCity.get(ip, api_key = 'free').country
    except:
        return np.nan
df_2['country'] = df_2.loc[:, 'IP_Address'].apply(IP_info_2)
print(df_2.head())
print('Time:',str(time.time()-s_time)+'s')

print(type(DbIpCity.get('48.151.136.76',api_key = 'free')))
```

**Output**

```
       IP_Address country
0   48.151.136.76      US
1    94.9.145.169      GB
2   58.94.157.121      JP
3  193.187.41.186      AT
4   125.96.20.172      CN

Time: 80.53318452835083s 

<class 'ip2geotools.models.IpLocation'>
```

A reason why the huge time difference could be due to the Data structure of the output, **i.e** direct subsetting from *dictionaries* seems way more efficient than indexing from  the specicialized  *ip2geotools.models.IpLocation* object.

Also, the output of the 1st method is dictionary containing geo-location data, subset respecitively to obtain needed info:

```
x = geolite2.reader().get('48.151.136.76')
print(x)

>>>
    {'city': {'geoname_id': 5101798, 'names': {'de': 'Newark', 'en': 'Newark', 'es': 'Newark', 'fr': 'Newark', 'ja': 'ニューアーク', 'pt-BR': 'Newark', 'ru': 'Ньюарк'}},

 'continent': {'code': 'NA', 'geoname_id': 6255149, 'names': {'de': 'Nordamerika', 'en': 'North America', 'es': 'Norteamérica', 'fr': 'Amérique du Nord', 'ja': '北アメリカ', 'pt-BR': 'América do Norte', 'ru': 'Северная Америка', 'zh-CN': '北美洲'}}, 

'country': {'geoname_id': 6252001, 'iso_code': 'US', 'names': {'de': 'USA', 'en': 'United States', 'es': 'Estados Unidos', 'fr': 'États-Unis', 'ja': 'アメリカ合衆国', 'pt-BR': 'Estados Unidos', 'ru': 'США', 'zh-CN': '美国'}}, 

'location': {'accuracy_radius': 1000, 'latitude': 40.7355, 'longitude': -74.1741, 'metro_code': 501, 'time_zone': 'America/New_York'}, 

'postal': {'code': '07102'}, 

'registered_country': {'geoname_id': 6252001, 'iso_code': 'US', 'names': {'de': 'USA', 'en': 'United States', 'es': 'Estados Unidos', 'fr': 'États-Unis', 'ja': 'アメリカ合衆国', 'pt-BR': 'Estados Unidos', 'ru': 'США', 'zh-CN': '美国'}}, 

'subdivisions': [{'geoname_id': 5101760, 'iso_code': 'NJ', 'names': {'en': 'New Jersey', 'es': 'Nueva Jersey', 'fr': 'New Jersey', 'ja': 'ニュージャージー州', 'pt-BR': 'Nova Jérsia', 'ru': 'Нью-Джерси', 'zh-CN': '新泽西州'}}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [GeoIP](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python), which has both a free and a paid version. There is also a convenient [Python API](http://www.maxmind.com/app/python).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ipapi` API. It is much better than `ip2geotools` (no requirement to install Visual C++ 14.0) or `hostip.info API` (not very accurate) or others mentioned above that *may* not go beyond country.

```
import requests

arr1=["ipaddress1","ipaddress2",...,"ipaddress300"]
    
def get_location(ip):
    ip_address = ip
    response = requests.get(f'https://ipapi.co/{ip_address}/json/').json()
    location_data = {
        "ip": ip_address,
        "city": response.get("city"),
        "region": response.get("region"),
        "country": response.get("country_name")
    }
    return location_data

for ip in arr1:
    print(get_location(ip))
```

For visualization you have many options such as [basemap, folium, geopandas and plotly](https://kanoki.org/python-plotting-latitude-and-longitude-from-csv-on-map-using-basemap-folium-geopandas-and-plotly).

Taken with thanks from https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-get-location-information-of-ip-address-using-python/